# How to change widget brightness in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

In CSS I can use filter to change brightness. It's easy to make button hover effect.

```
filter: brightness(1.1);

filter: brightness(0.9);
```

Is there any way to change widget brightness in Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

If your main goal is giving a hover effect on a button, you can use the combination of animated container(for the effect) and inkwell(onHover method to notify when hovering happens)

```
AnimatedContainer(
      height: 70,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          top: (isHover) ? 25 : 30.0, bottom: !(isHover) ? 25 : 30),
      child: Container(
        height: 30,
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Text("Hover Button"),
          onHover: (val) {
            print("Val--->{}$val");
            setState(() {
              isHover = val;
            });
          },
        ),
```

Comment: No, I want to change brightness.

Answer (score -1):

We do this in flutter

```
Colors.red.withOpacity(1.1);
```